# Can't CC / BCC from Hide My Email on MacBook Air / Ventura

Tags: mail.app, email, ventura

MacBook Air M1 2020
OS: Ventura 13.1

I have received a reply to my Hide my Email address, in which two other people are CC'd. However, when I hit Reply All (desktop), the To address is immutable, the CC box is empty and both that and BCC won't let me add another address in. When I try the same on my iPhone, the CCs are there and it works as expected.

This is so comprehensive that it feels like a deliberate policy choice by Apple, rather than a bug, but I can't find anything about it in their literature and it's strange to diverge so much from iOS.